# HTML5 input pattern (prevent first to 0)

Tags: regex, html, input

I try to let the user input a version number.
With a minimum of 3 numbers in pairs of 2 like:

**1.1.1**

or

**11.11.11**

or

**11.10.11.1**

I only NOT want that the first number starts with a **0** like:

**01.1.1**

or

**0.11.11.11**

I not want the **0** (*i am very happy i came this far*)

```html
<form onsubmit="alert('Submitted.');return false;">
 <input type="text" required="" pattern="((^|\.)(([1-9]?\d))){2,4}$" value="" placeholder="Try it out.">
 <input type="submit" value="»">
</form>
```

Comment: Try `[1-9]\d*(\.\d\d?){1,3}`

Comment: You don't need anchors either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```css
input:valid {
  color: black;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="alert('Submitted.');return false;">
    <input type="text" required pattern="[1-9]\d?(?:\.\d{1,2}){1,3}" value="" placeholder="Try it out.">
    <input type="submit" value="»">
</form>
```

The pattern will be translated to `/^(?:[1-9]\d?(?:\.\d{1,2}){1,3})$/` and will match

- `^(?:` - start of the string with a non-capturing group start
- `[1-9]\d?` - a digit from `1` to `9` and then any optional digit
- `(?:\.\d{1,2}){1,3}` - 1 to 3 occurrences of:

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `\d{1,2}` - any 1 or 2 digits
- `)$` - end of the automatically generated group and end of the string.

See the [**regex demo online**](https://regex101.com/r/NNUJMU/1).